# Syntax errors while trying to parse out extra characters in phone numbers

Tags: t-sql, syntax-error

Trying to get rid of all "(", "-", etc.. so that just #'s remain.  I am very new to SQL, pretty much learning it on the fly, so I am unfamiliar with much of the syntax.  There is a syntax error near 'END' and I'm not sure what it is.  I have the variables declared and all the data selected prior to this part of the code.

```
                SET @WorkPhone=''
        SET @Loop=0
        WHILE @Loop<=@VPMWorkPhoneLength
            BEGIN
                SET @Char=substring(@VPMWorkPhone,@Loop,1)
                IF @Char<>'(' and @Char<>' ' and @Char<>'-' and @Char<>' '
                    BEGIN
                        SET @WorkPhone=@WorkPhone + @Char
                    END
                SET @Loop=(@Loop+1)
            END
```

The next part of the code looks exactly the same except it is for variable @Fax instead.  It, too, has a syntax error near 'END'

Comment: This isn't pure SQL. Please add a tag for the stored procedure language used (e.g. T-SQL).

Comment: duplicate of this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378441/sql-server-2000-how-do-i-return-only-the-number-from-a-phone-number-column

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why that code works and mine doesn't.

Comment: Besides, I'm not asking how to parse out the characters, necessarily.  I think I know how to do that.  I'm trying to find where my syntax error is

Comment: I don't see any syntax errors. The message is probably due to errors above in the code

Comment: when I parse the code above this, it checks out fine, but when i parse this section it gives me an error

Comment: I copied-and-pasted your given code sample into SSMS, added declarations for the variables, and ran it fine with no error. Can you please post your entire script? I think you may have a missing "END" in one of your "BEGIN...END" blocks farther up the script.

Comment: @Aaroneus anyway, this code fragment looks just fine except for missing variable declarations. The problem is somewhere outside and if you provide full code it would be easier to spot the error.

Comment: It is working just fine now. I had copy/pasted the code from a previous stored procedure (written by a former employee) to get to this point, so I figured why not just start from scratch and copy/paste again. Now it works. I didn't change anything... but it works.

Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @RobertN you are correct!  After looking at the two side by side, it looks like the one that was giving me errors has an END missing.  Not sure how it got deleted.  Thank you guys for helping a newbie!